# Can the object of “bénéficier de qch” be a person?

Tags: verbes

[“bénéficier de qch” means to “benefit from sth”.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de)

I would like to know how to say for example “I’m benefiting from my new lecturer.”, thus can the object of “bénéficier de qch” be a person instead of **qch**? I’m unable to get an answer from [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/B%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier). Could somebody help me with this please?

If the answer is no, how do you say “I’m benefiting from my new lecturer.”

Is it “Je suis au bénéfice de mon nouveau professeur.”?

Comment: No "Je suis au bénéfice de" refers to being the recipient of say a rent, or the holder of some title (licence, certificate...etc.). In this case I would for example say "je gagne beaucoup à avoir ce nouveau professeur" or simply "j'apprends beaucoup avec..."

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse  your response is incorrect. It’s written in the dictionary by Oxford Languages that the definition of “benefit” is “to receive an advantage”. So the sentence “I’m benefiting from my new lecturer.” simply means “I’m receiving advantages from my new lecturer.”

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse What is imprecise about it?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse The advantage of the verb is that you don’t need to specify how.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse It is if the aim is to be vague for example.

Answer (score 1):

The object of *beneficier* is always something, never someone.

If you want to stay close to "I’m benefiting from my new lecturer" and still use *bénéficier*, you can say:

> Je bénéficie des services/des conseils/du soutien de mon nouveau professeur.

Comment: Thank you @jlliagre ! Is there another what to say “I’m benefitting from my lecturer.” where the object of the verb is a person?

Comment: *Je progresse bien grâce à mon professeur*, *J'apprends beaucoup de mon professeur*.

Comment: Hm... so there’s no french verb which is explicitly to do with “benefitting”? Cool, thank you @jlliagre 

Comment: By the way, what about “Je suis au bénéfice de mon professeur.”?

Comment: That's a bizarre sentence. That would probably be understood as "I'm at the service of my teacher" or "I'm one of my teacher's assets"...

Comment: I thought it would mean “I’m in the benefit of my teacher.”

Comment: In the expression *être au bénéfice de*, the object has a gain thanks to the subject.

Comment: So then it should “Mon professeur est au bénéfice de moi.” ?

Comment: You mean *Mon professeur est à mon bénéfice* but still very awkward.

Answer (score 1):

"[There is no French verb which has explicitly to do with “benefiting”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/can-the-object-of-b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de-qch-be-a-person#comment90775_44568)": that's not accurate.

> [Je gagne beaucoup à avoir ce nouveau professeur.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/can-the-object-of-b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de-qch-be-a-person#comment90772_44560) [it's to my advantage]
>  [J'apprends
> beaucoup avec ce nouveau professeur.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/can-the-object-of-b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de-qch-be-a-person#comment90772_44560) [learn a lot with]
>
> [Je progresse bien grâce à mon professeur.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/can-the-object-of-b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de-qch-be-a-person#comment90774_44568) [making progress]
>  [J'apprends beaucoup de
> mon professeur.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44560/can-the-object-of-b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier-de-qch-be-a-person#comment90774_44568) [learn a lot from]
>
> Je [tire bénéfice](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_b%C3%A9n%C3%A9fice)/[parti](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_parti)/[profit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_profit)/[avantage](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_avantage) des cours
> avec/de mon nouveau professeur. [draw some benefit from, see links]
>  Je comprends vraiment mieux avec mon nouveau professeur.
> [understand way better]
>  J'obtiens de meilleures notes avec ce nouveau professeur. [getting better grades]
>
> Avoir ce nouveau professeur m'aide. [helps me, generally]
> J'obtiens un avantage (quelconque) à avoir/avec ce nouveau professeur.
> [gain an unspecified advantage]
>  Le changement de professeur me
> fait du bien. [the change... does me good]